# iOS 5 - Camera Overlay Clone

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there an open source nib out that that's a clone of the overlay view that Apple uses for its Camera.app? I'm currently using `UIImagePickerController` with `picker.showCameraControls = YES`, but I need to tweak the functionality ever so slightly.

I've been thinking of subclassing the `UIImagePickerController`, but would that give me more control over `takePicture`? Specifically, I want to be able to call that method without forcing the user to leave the interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is for.    The documentation shows how to set up a captureSession, from there it's all cake!

Comment: Can this be used for still images, too? It looks like it's video and audio only.

Comment: This uses a custom overlay. My question is: is there a way to get the exact overlay that's made by Apple in Camera.app? I don't need AVCaptureSession if I'm using a custom overlay, so I don't think that's what I'm looking for...

Comment: The camera.app uses that AVCaptureSession overlay and a custom UIToolbar (they overrode drawrect to get that gray color, but you can use the appearance API's in iOS 5.x).